# What does a validation set batch size of one mean? (Keras)

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, validation, keras

In Keras there is an option to set the validation set batch_size to one:

```
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(valid_path, ... batch_size=1)
```

Is it correct that the model then just uses one object from the validation data to validate the model after each training data epoch? If that is the case my model validation score should fluctuate a lot. But it runs without any problems, keeps improving and seems to be using many validation objects for evaluation. Can someone explain this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't use just one object, it uses all objects, but evaluates them one-by-one. Changing batch size for evaluation doesn't really do anything, other than adjusting the memory footprint of the graph.